# Why does the latest raspbian update disable some wifi frequencies?

Tags: wifi, pi-4, pi-3b+, raspbian-buster

I started with a fresh installation of Raspberry Pi OS Lite (Release date: May 7th 2021, Kernel version: 5.10) and checked wifi state with `iw reg get` `iw list`.

```
global
country DE: DFS-ETSI
 (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
 (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW
 (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS, AUTO-BW
 (5470 - 5725 @ 160), (N/A, 26), (0 ms), DFS
 (5725 - 5875 @ 80), (N/A, 13), (N/A)
 (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

And then started the update to the latest version with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`.

After that update the wifi frequencies 5260-5700 were disabled.

| Freq. | Channel | after | before |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5170 MHz | 34 | disabled | disabled |
| 5180 MHz | 36 | 20.0 dBm | 20.0 dBm |
| 5190 MHz | 38 | disabled | disabled |
| 5200 MHz | 40 | 20.0 dBm | 20.0 dBm |
| 5210 MHz | 42 | disabled | disabled |
| 5220 MHz | 44 | 20.0 dBm | 20.0 dBm |
| 5230 MHz | 46 | disabled | disabled |
| 5240 MHz | 48 | 20.0 dBm | 20.0 dBm |
| 5260 MHz | 52 | disabled | 20.0 dBm (no IR, radar detection) |
| 5280 MHz | 56 | disabled | 20.0 dBm (no IR, radar detection) |
| 5300 MHz | 60 | disabled | 20.0 dBm (no IR, radar detection) |
| 5320 MHz | 64 | disabled | 20.0 dBm (no IR, radar detection) |
| 5500 MHz | 100 | disabled | 20.0 dBm (no IR, radar detection) |
| 5520 MHz | 104 | disabled | 20.0 dBm (no IR, radar detection) |
| 5540 MHz | 108 | disabled | 20.0 dBm (no IR, radar detection) |
| 5560 MHz | 112 | disabled | 20.0 dBm (no IR, radar detection) |
| 5580 MHz | 116 | disabled | 20.0 dBm (no IR, radar detection) |
| 5600 MHz | 120 | disabled | 20.0 dBm (no IR, radar detection) |
| 5620 MHz | 124 | disabled | 20.0 dBm (no IR, radar detection) |
| 5640 MHz | 128 | disabled | 20.0 dBm (no IR, radar detection) |
| 5660 MHz | 132 | disabled | 20.0 dBm (no IR, radar detection) |
| 5680 MHz | 136 | disabled | 20.0 dBm (no IR, radar detection) |
| 5700 MHz | 140 | disabled | 20.0 dBm (no IR, radar detection) |
| 5720 MHz | 144 | 13.0 dBm | disabled |
| 5745 MHz | 149 | 13.0 dBm | disabled |
| 5765 MHz | 153 | 13.0 dBm | disabled |
| 5785 MHz | 157 | 13.0 dBm | disabled |
| 5805 MHz | 161 | 13.0 dBm | disabled |
| 5825 MHz | 165 | 13.0 dBm | disabled |

What is the reason for that and how can can I fix it?

[There is a gist with the full output of iw and update log](https://gist.github.com/SirRufo/5759a8fe58c25b5b085d0514c3684b06)

Comment: @Milliways The listed output is from `iw reg get` - and my setup is a stock RPI 3B+ or stock RPI 4B (behaviour is the same on both, so to me it does not really matter)

Comment: @Milliways My wifi works too, but not on the disabled frequencies as it does before and I had to change the freq at the Access Point to get it working

Comment: Same issues here in .at since the last Upgrade... :( Might this maybe also connected with https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=985632 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `sudo apt update; sudo apt dist-upgrade -y; sudo reboot` there's a brand new update to the WiFi firmware packages to resolve this failure.

Comment: Yes, now it is back working as before

Answer (score 2):

It could be that DFS/TPC channels were disabled because they used to cause issues such as [this one](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=212107).

If you weren't affected by these problems, try getting WiFi chip firmware from an older Pi OS image. The files you need are located in `/lib/firmware/brcm/`, on my Pi 4 the `brcmfmac43455-sdio.*` files are used.

Changing the country might also help, but this may result in operating a non-compliant RF device, which, at least theoretically, could get you in trouble.